# Arduino - Simple class based unit testing with VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, arduino

I'd like to unit test single classes I wrote for the arduino platform with VS2015 Express (+VisualMicro).

By single classes I mean the focus is on RingBuffer.h + RingBuffer.cpp. I do not want to emulate an arduino or even run the unit tests on the real hardware.

I have two projects in my solution:

- Project1 with the code that will run on arduino.
- Test1 which is a win32 console application that contains the tests and uses simple _ASSERTs to validate the output.

In both projects I use the *stdafx.h* to define my environment based on preprocessor directives, where I abstract hardware stuff. Example:

```
#if UNITTEST
typedef unigned short uint16_t
#define DISABLE_INTERRUPTS
#else
#include "Arduino.h"
typedef unsigned int uint16_t
#define DISABLE_INTERRUPTS cli()
#endif
```

When the project was smaller, I developed the class-implementations within the test project and then I copied the files to the arduino project. But this workflow sucks since the files are not sync.

How can I setup my solution that the unit test project uses the .cpp files from the real arduino code? I managed to include the header files easily by adding a new /INCLUDE directory. But I can't add the sources.
I always end up with LNK2019 errors "unresolved external symbol".

Comment: After reading tons of post... *does* anyone unittests on adruino?

Comment: For testing Arduino code as a PC program, see e.g. [Moon Phase Calendar for Arduino, using Pro Trinket](https://github.com/MarkMoene/MoonPhaseCalendar) and look in the [test](https://github.com/MarkMoene/MoonPhaseCalendar/tree/master/test) folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this one was really easy:

```
#include "../Project1/RingBuffer.cpp"
```

Thanks Martin for the demo project!